# Django - translations does not work

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add translations to my project. Since I'm not an expert, I want to test a very simple example at first.

I followed multiple tutorials including official documentation but I'm probably missing something.

What I've done so far:

**SETTINGS.PY:**

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
)


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ...
                'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
            ],
        },
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
# list of languages used
LANGUAGES = [
    ( 'en', _('English') ),
    ( 'fr', _('French') ),
]

# directory that will host po and mo files
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)
```

**models.py** (just one attribute changed to see effects in admin)

```
class Level(models.Model):
    LEVEL_CHOICES = (
        ('unknown', ugettext_lazy('Unknown')),
        ('standard', ugettext_lazy('Standard level')),
        ('professional', ugettext_lazy('Professional level')),
        ('native', ugettext_lazy('Native speaker level')),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=LEVEL_CHOICES, blank=False, null=False)
```

I've already installed [GETTEXT](http://mlocati.github.io/gettext-iconv-windows/)

OS: Windows 8.1 64 bit

Now what I expected to see are `.po` files inside `locale` directory.

So I runned:

```
django-admin makemessages
```

returned error:

```
CommandError: Can't find xgettext. Make sure you have GNU gettext tools 0.15 or
newer installed.
```

So I tried:

```
python manage.py makemessages --locale=fr_FR --locale=en_US
```

which returned:

```
CommandError: Can't find msguniq. Make sure you have GNU gettext tools 0.15 or n
ewer installed.
```

Do you guys know what I do wrong? I've read the documentation, maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: What is the output of `xgettext --version` from a command prompt?

Comment: Can you run msguniq from command line? It needs to be in your path for django to find it.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid - it's 0.19.6

Comment: @MadWombat Yes, I can. It works from command line.

Comment: Are you using django from a virtual environment?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Yes I do.

Comment: Activate the virtual environment from a command prompt, and then type `xgettext --version` do you get any errors?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Yes, 'xgettext' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Try deactivating, then reactivating your virtual environment.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Unfortunately it did not help. The same problem is still happening.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Restarting PC have helped. Thank you very much!